# Turn on nginx `client_body_in_file_only` for PUT method only

Tags: nginx, request, webdav, put

I'm building webdav backend application with nginx as a frontend. 
To reduce disc operations during upload I'm turning on `client_body_in_file_only`.
The problem is that this forces nginx to write down all of request bodies and slows down small requests (PROPFIND queries for example).

Is there any way to make nginx `client_body_in_file_only=on` for PUT methods only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the $request_method is "PUT", return "588", which will be handled by the named location block that has the `client_body_in_file_only=on;`.

```
server {

    error_page 588 = @saveinfile;

    if ($request_method = PUT) {
        return 588;
    }
    location / {

        # the usual stuff..
    }
    location @saveinfile {            
        client_body_in_file_only on;

        # the usual stuff..
    }

}
```

Comment: I've already tried that. Redirect with `try_files` isn't possible too. `nginx: [emerg] "client_body_in_file_only" directive is not allowed here`. http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: Updated the code to use a named location to turn on `client_body_in_file_only`. Give it a try..

Comment: Cool! Looks like the answer!